# On Local Langlands correspondences

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations, langlands-conjectures, reductive-groups

Both over global function fields and $p$-adic fields, we have a series of conjectures under the name of “geometric Langlands conjectures”.

Over global function fields of char $p$, they are due to Drinfeld, L. Lafforgue and V. Lafforgue. Over $p$-adic fields, they are due to Fargues.

What about over the complex numbers, and over the real numbers?

Over $p$-adic fields $K$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$, the formal affine line $\mathcal{O}[\![t]\!]$ plays a crucial role via Lubin–Tate theory.

In some geometric formulations of local Langlands over the complex numbers, it seems the punctured formal affine line also plays a crucial role.

My question is:

> (1) is there a *geometric Langlands correspondence*, at least in conjectural form, for reductive groups over *archimedean* local fields?
>
> (2) Does the formal affine line over an archimedean local field play a role in it, and if so, which role? Perhaps, somehow (how?), in analogy with local class field theory?

I'd appreciate some references.

**Refs.**

[Mirkovic–Vilonen - Geometric Langlands duality and representations of algebraic groups over commutative rings](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2007/166-1/p03)

[Frenkel - Lectures on the Langlands program and conformal field theory](http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512172)

Comment: Over C, see work of Edward Frenkel and Dennis Gaitsgory.  E.g., Frenkel's book "Langlands Correspondence for Loop Groups".  Over R, I recall seeing something by Nadler or Ben-Zvi.

Comment: I think it's misleading to say that geometric Langlands ala Gaitsgory is a geometrization/categorification of complex archimedian Langlands. Rather, it's an analogue of nonarchimedian Langlands over the complex numbers. On the other hand, as I understand it, Ben-Zvi & Nadler's "Loop Spaces and Langlands Parameters" (which I assume is the paper Marty was thinking of) tries to explain archimedian Langlands as a S^1-equivariant localization of geometric Langlands, both in the real and complex cases. I'm secretly hoping David Ben-Zvi sees this and writes an answer...

Comment: I agree with @dhy about the relationship between Frenkel-Gaitsgory and archimedean Langlands.  I think I misunderstood the question a bit.  Anyways, I think I should look at the paper of Ben-Zvi and Nadler!